# The android simulator is so so slow, is it possible to have a PC running android system with android studio?

Tags: android, simulator

How could developer benefit from it? Suppose that we have an "android version" android studio.

Comment: Better to use Genymotion: https://www.genymotion.com/features/

Answer (score 0):

You can install a virtual machine with Android. See: http://www.osboxes.org/android-x86/